# Android custom view not visible

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

I want to create a custom view based on a XML layout. The layout itself works fine, e.g. when opened in the visual editor. But when using my custom view class, it just is invisible. In the editor as well as on the actual device.

Here's my view class:

```
public class MyCustomClass extends RelativeLayout {

    public MyCustomClass (Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        View.inflate(context, R.layout.mycoollayout, this);
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the inflating? Or some other problem?

Comment: You need to post your XML. Guessing, though, that you're not using your class in the XML correctly. You need to write `<view class="">`; use the full class name and note the lower-case "v".

Comment: You can't do anything wrong when adding a custom view in IntelliJ. It fills out everything automagically. Thus the class attribute seems to be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Change 
View.inflate(context, R.layout.mycoollayout, this);
to 
inflate(getContext(),R.layout.mycoollayout, this);